# Angular routing shows only 404 Not found

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404

I use Angular routing. But if I go to route I get 404 error.
If I use it with localhost it works:

[image]

But if I try to access on server it doesn't work:
[image]

My app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SchwarzesBrettComponent } from './schwarzes-brett/schwarzes-brett.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'bla/:abteilung', component: SchwarzesBrettComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have `<base-href='/schwarzes-brett/'>` in index.html so "schwarzes-brett/" must be in URL

If I only type ns400gt:8020/schwarzes-brett/ it works - but not as expected:

[image]

It adds "SchwarzesBrettComponent" automaticly to URL. Thats wrong

Of course I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my app.component.html

At least here is my html-file schwarzes-brett.component.html:

```
<div class="p-grid">
  <div class="p-col-10" style="background-color: #008800; text-align: center;">
    <span class="uberschrift">Schwarzes Brett {{abt}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-2" style="background-color: #008800;">
    <img src="/schwarzes-brett/assets/gw2.png" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-2" class="hintergrund">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let dokument of dokumente" class="liste">
        <p-button [label]="dokument.titel" styleClass="p-button-success" 
         (onClick)="openDokument(dokument.id)"></p-button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-10" class="hintergrund-dokument">
    <app-dokument class="hintergrund-dokument"></app-dokument>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here my schwarzes-brett.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Dokument, ID } from '../_model/dokument';
import { ComponentCommunicationService } from '../_service/component-communication.service';
import { DbService } from '../_service/db.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schwarzes-brett',
  templateUrl: './schwarzes-brett.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schwarzes-brett.component.scss']
})
export class SchwarzesBrettComponent implements OnInit {

  dokumente: Array<Dokument>;
  abteilung: string;
  abt: string;

  constructor(
    private dbService: DbService,
    private ccs: ComponentCommunicationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
   ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.abteilung = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('abteilung');
    this.abt = this.abteilung.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.abteilung.slice(1);
    this.dbService.getDokumente(this.abteilung).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dokumente = data;
        this.openDokument(this.dokumente[0].id);
      }
    );
  }

  openDokument(id: number): void {
    const mId = new ID();
    mId.id = id;
    this.ccs.push(mId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives as to why this problem occurs, the ones that I have found and have been able to solve this type of problem are the following

1. You need an .htaccess file from your server where the project folder is located, to solve the 404 problem.
   In this link you will find more information, it depends on what server you have.
   https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml
2. What you upload to the server is not the "src" folder nor the "app" folder, you need to execute a command to compile the project and generate a "dist" folder, and inside this folder you will find the files that you will have to put in the server.

the command to send to production the application is

`ng built -prod -base-href="./"`

if the problem persists but still remains in production with an error similar to "unexpected token", try the following command

`ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none`

3. In the image of your application mounted on the server, you have an error of access to the path of your server, you need to enable your server requests from the domain that will perform the requests, you can search for CORS errors to configure the server.

I HOPE I HELPED YOU

> comment: In my opinion and experience it is not necessary in your
> "app-routing.module.ts" file to use the "{useHash: true}" in your
> imports, because that makes include in the route in # and
> aesthetically is not the best and for me would not be good practice

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to answer my question. To first Point: This is not my first Project. I have much more Projects on this server. Second Point: Yes I upload the files from the dist folder. I always did so. Third Point: I will have a look if this server is configured like the other I upload projects. Maybe this could solve the problem but I am pessimistic. I'll try. Thank you

Comment: I really don't know why but now it works. I didn't do anything... But thank you for your help.

Comment: hahaha is magic, I'm glad it's already working